# How to avoid "%{@timestamp}" to drop milliseconds in logstash?

Tags: timestamp, logstash, milliseconds

I'm trying to use the content of field @timestamp inside my file output:

```
output {
  file {
     message_format => "%{@timestamp} [%{client_id}] [%{thread_name}] %{level} [%{logger_name}] - %{message}"
     path => ...
   }
}
```

But it drops the milliseconds from @timestamp.

The original timestamp goes from this:

2014-05-28T10:04:46.**180**-03:00

To this:

2014-05-28 10:04:46 -0300

How can I use this field without losing milliseconds?
Also, I wanna extract the year,month,day from `@timestamp` to compose the path filename.

Can someone help me, please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want. I have test it and it is worked at me. If you have any problem please kindly let me know. cheers

Step 1: Add ruby plugin to your filter

```
filter {
    ruby {
        code => "
             event['@timestamp'] = event['@timestamp'].localtime('-03:00')
             event['logtime'] = event['@timestamp'].strftime('%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S.%L')
             event['filename'] = event['@timestamp'].strftime('%Y%m%d')
        "
    }
}
```

For this filter, we add a logtime field and filename field, which will output this

```
"logtime" => "20140529 01:46:40.755"
"filename" => "20140529"
```

Then, in the output you want change your config

```
output {
    file {
        message_format => "%{logtime} [%{client_id}] [%{thread_name}] %{level} [%{logger_name}] - %{message}"
        path => "/path/to/log/save/%{filename}.log"
    }
}
```

Change the `@timestamp` to `logtime` field and then use `filename` field in your output path.

Comment: That's great. But now, how can I avoid to output those "date fields" to elasticsearch, for example? I need the information only to compose the file output. I was trying to use the %{+...} format, but even when @timestamp is in localtime, the %{+...} format is always in UTC. Is there any way to use this format in localtime?

Comment: I have update the answer. Add the timestamp format convertion. Besides, I dont know what you need about avoid to output to elasticsearch. Because in the output config you mentioned at your question do not output to elasticsearch. Please update your answer or open a new question. Thank you

Comment: If you want output the timezone info, you can modify the format "%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S.%L" to "%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S.%L %Z" in the second line of ruby plugin

Comment: You can't use %{+...} format because logstash always convert to UTC. So, I have use ruby code to add a new field. Instead of using logstash plugin to add.

Comment: Let me elaborate.. Using your answer, I will end up with two new fields (logtime and filename), right? If I use an elasticsearch output too, those fields will be stored in elasticsearch. Is there any way to do the same thing you did (which btw worked like charme) without have to store those fields? Thank you very much.

Comment: Due to your output do not say your have use ES. So, i thought you only use file output. Yes! the field created will save to ES too. I think there is no other thing you can did without store those fields. I didn't have %{+...} because now this plugin will not output to millisecond!